# Abort from a .bashrc script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, session, login-script

I know the `.bashrc` script must be run like `source .bashrc` or `. .bashrc` so changes in exports are kept during the session, but i need to abort from half the bashrc script without exiting the session.

Currently i'm doing a binary search of a point where i issue a command which assumes the existence of a tty. This is to avoid getting the message `stdin: is not a tty`. So the easiest way is to *break*  the execution of the bashrc script, but i haven't found a way to do so.

How do i **abort** from **half** the execution inside the **.bashrc** script **w/o ending the session**? (aka using the exit command)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `return` command to "exit" your script. It's usually an error to use `return` outside of a function, but you can think of the entire script as a function if it is being `source`d.

Comment: I just realized that. Works on CentOS 6.4 x86_64. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
if [ yourbreakcondition ]; then
    ...
else
   ...
   The rest of bashrc here
   ...
fi
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution i was trying to avoid. I'm happily choosing your option if no simpler solution comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Just call return within your bashrc.

Example

```
if [ true ]
then
    return
fi
```